# Eclipse Tomcat instance trying to initialize spring beans from package not in source

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7, spring-boot

I am trying to run a `tomcat 7` instance through `eclipse` containing the `WAR` of a particular package in my workspace.  When I start it up I get an exception related to the creation of a bean in a separate package (the bean is not at all referenced in the spring configuration or the code of the package I am deploying).  Why is tomcat trying to initialize beans from a separate package that is not included in the source of the tomcat instance?

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reloadAndFlip': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

Comment: I am hopping 'reloadAndFlip' should be your own bean, can you put whole stacktrace and related configuration files here to get more idea.

Comment: Yeah. please put the whole stacktrace, It should tell us more. Are You using xml context config?

Comment: "deployAndFlip" is referenced anywhere in your war.

Comment: Don't forget Eclipse classpath also includes TEST dependencies... Also, be very careful when using SpringSource STS are run your application as a "Spring Boot App": it also sometimes mess with the classpath.
Advice is you start your application with --debug and look for classpath information dumped by `ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason why the bean was being instantiated was because of a  in spring XML. Sorry for not pasting the full contents sooner